# set notification failed for cordova-plugin-ble-central

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, cordova-plugins

I've been playing with this plugin for a few days, trying to have a cordova app and a BLE device talk to each other. The device is a so called "itag", a keyring bought on ebay, purpose of which is ~= "don't loose your keys".

What I could do:
-connect to the device and get some of its characteristics
-read the state of the button and also the battery level using `ble.read(..)`
-make the device ring using `ble.writeWithoutResponse(..)`

What I could not do (and this is the reason for this post):
-be notified when the device button is pressed.

`ble.startNotification(device.id, "ffe0", "ffe1", success, fail)` result is fail function answering:
"set notification failed for 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

Here are the device characteristics published when connected:

```
{"name":"MLE-15","id":"FF:FF:F0:00:7D:A2","advertising":{},"rssi":-56,
"services":["1800","180f","1802","ffe0"],
"characteristics":[
{"service":"1800","characteristic":"2a00","properties":["Read","Notify"]},
{"service":"1800","characteristic":"2a01","properties":["Read"]},
{"service":"180f","characteristic":"2a19","properties":["Read","Notify"]},
{"service":"1802","characteristic":"2a06","properties":["WriteWithoutResponse","Write","Notify"]},
{"service":"ffe0","characteristic":"ffe1","properties":["Read","Notify"]}]}
```

Here is the code:

```
ble.scan([], 5, scan_success, scan_fail);

        function scan_success(device) {
            ble.connect(device.id, connect_success, connect_fail);
        }
        function scan_fail() {
            alert('error during scan');
        }

        function connect_success(device) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(device));
            ble.startNotification(device.id, "ffe0", "ffe1", success, fail);
        }
        function connect_fail(device) {
            alert('error during connect');
        }       


        var success = function(buffer) {
            // Decode the ArrayBuffer into a typed Array based on the data you expect
            var data = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            alert("device answers: " + data[0]);
            }

        var fail = function(buffer) {
            alert(buffer);
            }
```

Any help appreciated!